# Socket communication across multiple servers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I have a somewhat unique project which needs to involve 2 way communication on long running applications. Basically I will run a server.js app on a local server that will communicate with other devices on the local network. I have a pretty good understanding of Node.js and Socket.IO but this is a bit tricky for me because I'd like to run the application from the command line on say a raspberry PI.

A basic idea of what I want is...

- Main server receiving, processing and sending information to and from external devices.
- External devices run by way of raspberrypi's and GPIO inputs. They need to be able to receive commands and send data back to the main server at will. I'd like to avoid polling if possible.

Currently my only idea is to use HTTP requests and an API structure to send data through way of a rest API on both but this seems bulky. I'd love to see a way that they can communicate in a way similar to Socket.IO with eachother.

Comment: I think HTTP requests are quite common for this scenario. BPEL, for example, does this very thing with HTTP.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking this might be my only route. I know many commercial products that do this, like Nest but just checking other options, possibly concerned with latency and polling rates

Comment: Well, you can just have both clients also serve requests, so each client will provide a callback url. This should alleviate the polling.

Comment: Why not use TCP sockets?